# ZeroMQ SUB Socket receives empty frames

Tags: zeromq

I have problem establishing **`PUB/SUB`** communication in `ZeroMQ` (wrapped in **`clrzmq4`** ).

Although I'm using a `.NET` wrapper ( `clrzmq4` ), it actually uses `libzmq`, so I believe that the problem stands for ( can be solved in ) any programming language.

When I **set `socket.SubscribeAll()`** the subscriber receives **empty frames**.

Although publisher sends single-frame message, containing `X` bytes, subscriber receives a single **empty** frame message. If publisher sends a multi-frame message, each frame non-empty, subscriber receives multi-frame message, but all frames are empty.

If I **set** `socket.Subscribe( "123" )`, subscriber **behaves normally** ( it receives all "123xxxx..." messages ).

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens, if you **set `socket.Subscribe( "" )`** - i.e. **not** using `.SubscribeAll()` method, but setting the `TOPIC-filter` value explicitly to an empty string? Besides this, it is always fair to check and post also what `ZeroMQ` API versions are being used on both sides ( `PUB` -side system/API + `SUB` -side system/API details ), would you update?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I've just found the problem and the solution.

Comment: I am glad, that the above posted proposal to **set `socket.Subscribe( "" )`** did indeed help you to isoloate the root cause of the problem. ( + yes, Doron is everywhere and be gratefull for his immense help & support ).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem is **not in `ZeroMQ` / `clrzmq`**, but my other code. The problem is very interesting and you can check [here](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/2077) for details, but it is very unlikely that anyone else can run to the same problem.